# Use of "абсолютно" as negative sentence-word response

Tags: узус, наречия, отрицание

Based on a limited sample of native Russian-speaking friends, I've come to understand that the adverb  "абсолютно" used as a sentence-word in a response is synonymous with "no" as in:

-- Неужели Вы врали?

-- Абсолютно!

More recently I've come to doubt that this usage is as widely understood as I thought, and it probably depends on context. I would appreciate some clarification and possibly some linguistic reference similar to this article https://refdb.ru/look/2896246-pall.html which, ironically, deals with a similar problem in English.

Answer (score 3):

The adverb **абсолютно** doesn't have a negative connotation. It is a degree adverb meaning **полностью, совсем, совершенно** and can be used only in terms of confirmation either of positive or negative information. Consider the following examples.

> 1. – А он честный человек ?
>
> – Абсолютно.(positive) (– Is he a reliable person? - Absolutely/Sure.)
>
> 2.– Скажешь, это невозможно?
>
> – Абсолютно.(negative) (You'd say It's impossible, right? - Absolutely.)

Comment: The second example sounds OK to me (since _абсолютно невозможно_ is a proper combination) while the reply in the first one doesn't seem perfect: it is equivalent to **абсолютно можно** which is too informal (the question matching the reply better could be like this: **во всем** ли на него можно положиться? The complete answer = абсолютно во всём).

Answer (score 2):

The reply doesn't sound correct to me here (it should be smth. like **Безусловно** instead), it sounds as informal as "*я вам абсолютно врал*" (as if it were a literal  translation from English; proper version: **безусловно, я вам врал**). The word **абсолютно** is almost never used as an adverb *on its own* and is mainly combined with adjectives, e. g. **абсолютно голый** (*- Он что, был голый? - Абсолютно!*)*. And I can't think of an example, where *абсолютно* could be used as a reply confirming something negated indirectly.

**P.S.** *Such a short reply is also possible to a question with (абсолютно) **всё** or **ничего** (*not a verb*) in focus, since **абсолютно всё** и **абсолютно ничего** are correct combinations:

> -- Неужели ваша собака **всё** понимает?
>   -- Абсолютно (всё).

With direct negation:

> -- Он что, **ничего** не понял?
>   -- Абсолютно (ничего).

Comment: just for OP's information, for me, the response *абсолютно* sounds perfectly normal in that example.